# Shiurim of Rabbi Yitzchak Berkovits

Tags: halacha, niddah, adult-learning, contemporary-halacha, issur-vheter

Does anyone have the shiurim of [Rabbi Yitzchak Berkovits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchak_Berkovits) which he gives in his Kollel(not his daily Mishna Berura Shiur)? There are only a few on the Jerusalem Kollel [website](https://www.thejerusalemkollel.com).

Comment: I don't think he wants the shiurim he gives to hisi kollel to be publicly available. Anyone who has them is unlikely to share. What kind of shiurim are you looking for? Thousands of his shiurim over the past 30 years are available online.

Comment: Kol halashon has lot of them. I don't know about the kollel shiurim per se.

Comment: @robev On Hilchos Nidda or Issur V'Heter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Mi Yodeah MiZeh! Rav Yitzchok Berkovitz has over 1,000 shiurim shared [here](https://torahdownloads.com/s-225-rabbi-yitzchak-berkowitz.html) on TorahDownloads.com, a whole lot [here](https://www.kolhalashon.com/New/Shiurim.aspx?Path=English%7CEHalach%7CR0120-1&English=True&PageNum=6&Order=4) on Kol Halashon, and some more on his kollel webpage [here](https://www.thejerusalemkollel.com/online-classes/).